# Sumar días a una fecha en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date

Buenas, tengo el siguiente código en el cual me piden que coja la fecha actual y le sume 3 días para simular la devolución de una película.

Bueno con la fecha de hoy "12/01/2018" al sumarle los 3 días me sale como resultado que el día de la devolución es "15/01/2018" lo cual es correcto, pero si pones que la fecha actual es "30/01/2018" al sumarle los 3 días queda en "33/01/2018". Como podría validarlo para que me saliese que la fecha de devolución en ese caso fuese "03/02/2018". Espero haberme explicado correctamente.

Código:

```
function devolucionPelicula()
{
    fecha = new Date();
    dia = fecha.getDate();
    mes = fecha.getMonth()+1;// +1 porque los meses empiezan en 0
    anio = fecha.getFullYear();

    document.write("Fecha actual: "+dia+"/"+mes+"/"+anio);
    document.write("<br>Fecha devolucion: "+(dia+3)+"/"+mes+"/"+anio);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

La función [`Date.setDate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate) permite introducir valores fuera del rango habitual de un mes, siendo reajustado el mes y/o año en caso de que salirse de éstos:

> If the `dayValue` is outside of the range of date values for the month, `setDate()` will update the Date object accordingly. For example, if `0` is provided for `dayValue`, the date will be set to the last day of the previous month.

En castellano:

> Si `dayValue` está fuera del rango de días de un mes, `setDate()` actualizará el objeto `Date` acorde. Por ejemplo, si se proporciona `0` para `dayValue`, la fecha se fijará al último día del mes anterior.

Por lo que tu código podría ser:

```js
function devolucionPelicula()
{
    fecha = new Date();
    entrega = new Date();
    dia = fecha.getDate();
    mes = fecha.getMonth()+1;// +1 porque los meses empiezan en 0
    anio = fecha.getFullYear();
    entrega.setDate(entrega.getDate() + 3);

    document.write(
      "Fecha actual: " +
      fecha.getDate() + "/" +
      (fecha.getMonth()+1) + "/" +
      fecha.getFullYear()
    );
    document.write(
      "<br>Fecha devolución: " +
      entrega.getDate() + "/" +
      (entrega.getMonth()+1) + "/" +
      entrega.getFullYear()
    );
}
devolucionPelicula();
```

Comment: Te entiendo, me ha pasado xD

Comment: Jajajaja, gracias, pero no es necesario, a ver si encontras más metidas de pata XD

Answer (score 3):

No tienes más que utilizar el método `setDate` para establecer el día de la fecha. Si el número de día sobrepasa el último día del mes pasa automáticamente al mes siguiente:

```js
var fecha3001 = new Date(2018, 0, 30);
console.log('Fecha inicial: ', fecha3001.toLocaleDateString());
fecha3001.setDate(33);
console.log('Fecha final: ', fecha3001.toLocaleDateString());
```

Así te podría quedar:

```js
function devolucionPelicula()
{
    var hoy = new Date();
    var devolucion = new Date();
    devolucion.setDate(hoy.getDate() + 3);

    console.log("Fecha actual: ", hoy.toLocaleDateString());
    console.log("Fecha devolucion: ", devolucion.toLocaleDateString());
}

devolucionPelicula();
```

Answer (score 2):

Tienes que realizar la suma de días con los métodos que te proporciona JavaScript, en este caso el método [setDate](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate), no a tus variables numéricas por separado ya que no tendrá ninguna lógica de fechas (a no ser que se la ofrezcas claro).

```js
const europeanFormat = (date) => `${date.getDate()}/${date.getMonth() + 1}/${date.getFullYear()}`;
    
const date = new Date();
document.write(europeanFormat(date)+'<br/>');

date.setDate(date.getDate() + 3 /* días a sumar */);
document.write(europeanFormat(date));
```

Answer (score 2):

A la hora de sumar los días permitidos para la devolución, necesitas hacerlo dentro del *Date.setDate()* de la fecha de devolución. Espero que te ayude

```js
function devolucionPelicula()
{ 
    // Creamos una fecha (en el día actual)
    var fecha = new Date();
    var dia = fecha.getDate();
    var mes = fecha.getMonth() + 1;
    var anio = fecha.getFullYear();

    // Cantidad de dias permitidos para devolverlo
    var diasDevolucion = 3;

    // Creamos la fecha de devolucion
    var fechaDevolucion = new Date();
    // Sumamos los dias a la fecha
    fechaDevolucion.setDate(fechaDevolucion.getDate() + diasDevolucion);

    // Obtenemos el dia, mes y año de la fecha de devolucion
    var diaDevolucion = fechaDevolucion.getDate();
    var mesDevolucion = fechaDevolucion.getMonth() + 1;
    var anioDevolucion = fechaDevolucion.getFullYear();

    // Lo muestras en el HTML
    document.write("Fecha actual: " + dia + " - " + mes + " - " + anio );
    document.write("Fecha devolucion: " + diaDevolucion + " - " + mesDevolucion + " - " + anioDevolucion);

}

devolucionPelicula();
```