# Comprobar 30/02/yyyy con javascript

Tags: javascript

estoy intentando comprobar que los datos del usuario sean válidos.

Tengo el problema cuando intento comprobar fechas como:

30/02/2018, o 32/01/2018, las crea pero la de febrero la pone con días de marzo, y la de enero con febrero, aumentando dichos días y aumentando los meses.

Se me ha ocurrido entonces comprobar si mantiene los números de mes y día después de la conversación y tampoco funciona.

Lo he probado con **11/07/2018**

```
                        console.log("mon", mon);
                        date = new Date(year, mon - 1, day);
                        valid = !isNaN(date.valueOf());

                        console.log("date", date);
                        console.log("valid", valid);


                        if (date.getDay() === day) {
                            console.log("dia es el mismo");
                        } else {
                            console.log("dia cambio");
                        }

                        if (date.getDate() === mon) {
                            console.log("mes es el mismo");
                        } else {
                            console.log("mes cambio");
                        }

                        console.log("----");
                        console.log("date.getDay()" , date.getDay());
                        console.log("date.getDate()" , date.getDate());

                        if (!valid) {
                            format = false;
                        }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/130587/53715 --> Mira esta respuesta, la cual creo que te puede servir.

Comment: usualmente esto se soluciona evitando que el usuario pueda escoger por si mismo dia-mes-año ¿cómo? pues usando alguna librería de `datetimepicker`

Comment: El 30 de Febrero es el 2 de Marzo. Las opciones eran lanzar un error o asumir que es dos días después del 28 de febrero y Javascript suele elegir no lanzar errores

Comment: pero no sabes cuándo van a poner 30 o 32 de febrero o para los meses de enero que te pongan un 33... Y a has visto que con una fecha válida que no debería cambiar, ha cambiado...

Comment: Estás usando getDay (día de la semana, de 0 a 6) en lugar de getDate (día del mes)

Comment: No ha fallado. El miércoles (day 3) 11 (day 11) de Julio (mon 7). Está perfecto.  La gracia de esta lógica es que si tomas el 15 de febrero y le agregas 20 días el sistema por debajo calcula si el año es bisiesto y en qué día de marzo caes.  Como te dijeron, si esto es problemático, una un widget donde se pinche la fecha en vez de digitarla